# how to send low level wifi message?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

Is there any low level access to the androids wifi transmitter?

Obviously each android phone has a radio transmitter / receiver.

So how does one tell that transmitter to transmit say the letter "o" or the number 1
rather than a packet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always send a packet, what you can change is the payload that, in your case, can be a  string with only a "o" or a number. The packet is built according to the ISO/OSI stack http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model tho some levels are not always present.

Comment: so what is the lowest level that android allows access to?

Comment: With Android API you can actually do different things, but I think that the lowest level is DL. For example you can get Data Link as well as Network layer informations, like AP SSID or IP or even RSSI (you can find the whole list here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html). The point is that you can't "play" with inner API functions so if you are looking for something that is not provided by Android you have to build your own custom ROM.